# Is it normal to get a badge for reviewing edits when I'm not allowed to review edits?

Tags: support, review, badges

I saw that I received the 'Custodian' badge for reviewing suggested edits, but my rep doesn't allow me to review suggested edits.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2278/custodian?userid=2777181

I don't remember the action that lead to the attribution of this badge, but I never got to review a suggested edit.

Comment: I would guess it was a suggested edit on one of your own posts.

Comment: @Bart Yet I don't see one in the activity on his profile.  So it'd have to have been deleted too.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking for the same thing @Servy. Don't see the evidence yet.

Comment: @Bart oh, I can get a badge for that? I don't remember this event, but I it's at least plausible.

Comment: A mod would have to look through his deleted posts and see if he accepted any suggested edits on any of them.  Either that or he somehow gained 1k rep, reviewed an item, and then lost the rep again due to some combination of downvotes, serial upvote reversal, bounties, user removal, etc.

Comment: 'he somehow gained 1k rep, reviewed an item, and then lost the rep again due to some combination of downvotes' nope..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You got the Custodian badge for approving [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3927969) on your own post.

You then deleted the post 9 minutes after accepting that edit, which is what's causing it not to show up on your profile any longer.